# Is it safe to remove /usr/lib32 and /usr/libx32, on 64bit only Debian Linux 10

Tags: debian, fhs

Is it safe to remove `/usr/lib32`, `/usr/libx32` directories and their links on `/lib32`, `libx32`, on 64bit only (no multiarch enabled) Debian Linux 10? They are empty.
Since this new file system hierarchy is used, I'm considering removing them to reduce clutter in `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if they are empty, it’s safe to remove them. If you actually install packages which ship them (*e.g.* `libc6-x32`) and remove them, the directories are removed; so removing them manually in your case is fine.